# Is there a more efficient way than iterrows() in this situation?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a script that cleans some data. I have values in a column, *X*, that can sometimes be misspelled, so I'm trying to write a script that identifies that and corrects it. I am using fuzzywuzzy to perform fuzzy string matching.

*X* can be one of about 50 different values. However, I can use column *Y* (when the value in column *Y* is not null), which *X* functionally determines, to narrow the possible values *X* can be to about 5.

I use a separate dataframe (correct_values) containing the correctly spelled values for column *X*, and their corresponding *Y* values. The solution I have works but from my understanding, I know that .iterrows() is much slower and I'm curious if there is a better way of going about this?

Please let me know if you need further clarification =)

```
def cleanup_misspelled_X():

        # Checks for rows where X is invalid and not null
        # These rows's X value could be misspelled
        if (working_df[
                        (~working_df['X'].isin(correct_values['X'])) &
                        (~working_df['X'].isna())
                      ]).any:

            # If so, check if those same rows have a valid/present Y value.
            # If the row has a valid/present Y value, we can narrow down the
            # possible X values
            if (working_df[
                            (~working_df['X'].isin(correct_values['X'])) &
                            (~working_df['X'].isna()) &
                            (working_df['Y'].isin(correct_values['Y']))
                           ]).any:

                # If so, assign those records to a dataframe
                to_be_corrected_df = working_df[
                            (~working_df['X'].isin(correct_values['X'])) &
                            (~working_df['X'].isna()) &
                            (working_df['Y'].isin(correct_values['Y']))
                                                ]

                # Iterate through those rows
                for index, row in to_be_corrected_df.iterrows():

                    # If match is > 85%, fill the invalid X value with the match
                    if process.extractOne(
                           # value to attempt to match
                           row['X'],
                            # collection of values to match against 
                           correct_values.loc[correct_values['Y'] == row['Y']]['X']
                                         )[1] > 85:

                        working_df.loc[
                           working_df['row_identifier'] == row['row_identifier'],
                           ['X']] = \

                           process.extractOne(
                           row['X'],
                           correct_values.loc[correct_values['Y'] == row['Y']]['X']
                                             )[0]

                    else:
                        pass # for now 

            # If the row's X value is invalid and not null
            # and said row does not have a valid/present Y value
            if (working_df[
                            (~working_df['X'].isin(correct_values['X'])) &
                            (~working_df['X'].isna()) &
                            (~working_df['Y'].isin(correct_values['Y']))
                           ]).any:

                # Assign such rows to a dataframe
                to_be_corrected_df = working_df[
                            (~working_df['X'].isin(correct_values['X'])) &
                            (~working_df['X'].isna()) &
                            (~working_df['Y'].isin(correct_values['Y']))
                                                ]

                # Iterate through the dataframe
                for index, row in to_be_corrected_df.iterrows():

                    # If the proposed match is > 90% then fill the invalid X value 
                    # with the match
                    if process.extractOne(
                                        row['X'], 
                                        correct_values['X']
                                        )[1] > 90:

                        working_df.loc[
                            working_df['row_identifier'] == row['row_identifier'], 
                            ['X']] = \

                            process.extractOne(
                                        row['X'], 
                                        correct_values['X']
                                        )[0]

                    else:
                        pass # for now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**df.to_dict**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with tqdm like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for row in tqdm(df.to_dict('records')):
```

In your question replace this:

```
for index, row in to_be_corrected_df.iterrows():
```

with this:

```
for row in tqdm(to_be_corrected_df.to_dict('records')):
```